# How to compare a column from two different rows and display the percent difference between two columns

Tags: sql

I need to compare the `PickAlgoScore` from `Row1`, with the `PickAlgoScore` from `Row2`, and if the percent difference between both numbers is `> 50%`, then show me, otherwise, ignore.  I would further need to do this for every two rows in the table.

[image]

Comment: 1. Always tag with the dbms you are using. 2. You should always include your sample (input, expected output) as `formatted text` directly in your question, no links, pictures whatsoever.

Comment: Show you what?  What result set are you looking for?

Comment: I need to see the percent difference between the 71.05 and 49.715 between rows 1 and 2, and same for rows 3 and 4, and same for rows 5 and 6, etc...

Comment: How do you determine the row order/numbers? Table rows don't have any predefined order by default.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you didn't mention your rdbms version but normally you can do this kind of things with analytical functions (Windows functions). And in case of your question check out LEAD and LAG functions where you can compare a record with it's previous record.